# Third party payment methods are not redirecting to SUCCESS page

Tags: magento2, success-message

This is very strange. I am stuck for 2 months already on this.

All Magento provided payment methods works normally. Bank transfer, PayPal etc do redirect to the success page.

But any third party payment methods do not redirect to the success page, but they redirect to the empty cart page.

**All orders are created, payments are captured. But it won't show success page.**

Because all third party is not taking to the success page, I strongly believe it's something to do within my instance. My best guess is server related, but why PayPal works then?

Any help?

1. Magento 2.3.3
2. Php 7.2.x
3. Varnish
4. Redis